# jQuery 'on' not binding event to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, which is invoked immediately and binds a click event to elements.

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {
    var methods     = {},
    selector = $('.selector');

    methods.init = function () { 
        selector.find('> .section').on('click', function (e) {
          alert('hey');
        }
    }

    if (selector.length > 0) {
        methods.init();
    }

}(window, jQuery));
```

I needed it to also bind elements that had been added dynamically, so I changed to this:

```
var modules = modules || {};
modules.stuff = (function (window, $, undefined) {
    var methods     = {},
    selector = $('.selector');

    methods.init = function () {
        selector.find('> .section').on('click', function (e) {
          alert('hey');
        }
    }

    if (selector.length > 0) {
        methods.init();
    }


    return methods;

}(window, jQuery));
```

And then added dynamic elements, then called `modules.stuff.init();` I can see that the init function is ran but the click events don't fire?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the delegated signature of the `on()` method. Try this:

```
methods.init = function () {
    selector.on('click', '> .section', function (e) {
        alert('hey');
    }
}
```